# Window Phone 7 app in c# code

Tags: c#

I am designing a windows phone 7 app and I need to insert web contents into a page on my app how do I do this please. Do I create some sort of contents page? I don't want to direct it to the web page itself but have it displayed on the page of my app. Please can you help me.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431797%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) control. See the [sample app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402526%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I mostly do iOS development but you can check out this I think it is what you are looking for [WebView Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx).